# Getting posts / feed of specific facebook user with access token in open graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to getting posts(feed) of specific facebook user with access token in open graph.
The user is my friend, she agreed this operation by making a verbal promise.

I've got the token:

> `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxx&client_secret=xxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials`

But I can't see all posts(just public status messages).

```
Request => https://graph.facebook.com/100001958850690/posts?access_token=xxxxx&q=facebook
Response => {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#606) actor_id (100001958850690)  must be a connection of the viewer",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 606
   }
}
```

Is there no way can read public posts of specific/agreed user?